# How to update the multi level inner data in dynamodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have data inside the dyanomodb which is in the nested inner format like this :

```
{
  "inner0": {
    "inner1": {
      "inner2": {
        "inner3": {
          "name": "david",
          "address": "US"
        }
      }
    },
    "phone": "12345"
  }
}
```

How to update the address field. when I am trying to update the phone that is in two level it is updating but facing problem while updating the address or name field which is in the nested inner level.

```
methods.updateinfo = function(name){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var params = {
      TableName: tableName,
      Key: {
        'keyvalue': 12345
      },

      UpdateExpression: 'set #inner0.#inner1.#inner2.#inner3.#name = :name',

      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
       '#inner0':'inner0',
       '#inner1':'inner1',
       '#inner2':'inner2',
       '#inner3':'inner3',
       '#name': 'name'
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':name': name,
      },
      ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
    };
    docClient.update(params, function (err, data) {
      resolve(data.Attributes);
    });
  });
```

when I used this method I am getting query error.

```
[error] uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'Attributes' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Attributes' of null
```

Comment: can you show us the very error?

Comment: I am getting this error ==> [error] uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'Attributes' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Attributes' of null

Comment: Can you log the `err` returned in the callback? The error you are currently seeing is because `data` is `null`; `.update` is calling back with `err`.